# Check if there exists, in a dataframe, a row with all `NA`

Tags: r, dataframe

Check if there exists, in a dataframe, a row with all `NA`. For example, the answer for this dataframe is yes:

```
my.df <- data.frame(a=c(1, NA, 3), b=c(5, NA, NA))
```

but it is not true for the following

```
my.df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=c(5, NA, NA))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to create a function which converts the data to logical matrix (`is.na`), get the rowwise sum of the elements that are `NA`, check if it is equal to the number of columns and wrap if there are `any` rows having that meets

```
f1 <- function(dat) any(rowSums(is.na(dat)) == ncol(dat))

f1(my.df)
#[1] TRUE
f1(my.df2)
#[1] FALSE
```

NOTE: `rowSums` is vectorized and should be very fast

---

Or another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
f2 <- function(dat) {
     dat %>%
         filter(across(everything(), is.na)) %>%
         nrow %>% 
         magrittr::is_greater_than(0)
  }

f2(my.df)
#[1] TRUE
f2(my.df2)
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option can be:

```
#Code
myfun <- function(x)
{
  y <-apply(x,1,function(x) length(which(is.na(x))))
  any(y==ncol(x))
}
#Apply
myfun(my.df)
myfun(my.df2)
```

Output:

```
myfun(my.df)
[1] TRUE
myfun(my.df2)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
allNA <- apply(my.df, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
allNA
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
sum(allNA) # determine if there is at least 1 allNA row
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums` and `is.na`:

```
my.df[which(rowSums(is.na(my.df[]))==2),]
   a  b
2 NA NA
```

If you have dataframes with variable numbers of columns, you can use `length`:

```
my.df[which(rowSums(is.na(my.df[])) == length(my.df)),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option is using `any` + `Reduce` + `asplit`

```
any(Reduce("&", asplit(is.na(df), 2)))
```

where `df` is the input data.frame